# Mysql query not working if i add parameter dynamically in CI model

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have an sql `select` query with `where`. If I put a static value, it works fine. But if I use a parameter value like `$name`, it doesn't work. Here's my sample code:

I'm using codeigniter, this query written in model.

working query: (It returns a correct value)

```
function getid($email){    
  $query=$this->db->query('SELECT e_id FROM employee WHERE mail="test@gmail.com"');
}
```

not working query: (It returns null)

```
function getid($email){    
  $query=$this->db->query('SELECT e_id FROM employee WHERE mail="'.$email.'"');
}
```

Comment: In the second query you column is `email` and not `mail`. What is the correct column name?

Comment: Check that , if you are getting the value in $email variable?

Comment: sorry, written mistake i edited my question again, this is not because of column name.. i changed that..

Comment: why you using query like this? why not using CI active record. like get_where,where. Asking debugging help is off-topic at SO.Your question title 'Does not work' means you want us to debug it where the mistake is. I wonder why people up voted it.

Comment: i am getting the value of $email in model @Toretto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to `var_dump` your `$email` variable as it may be null. If not then try the following query.

```
$query=$this->db->query("SELECT e_id FROM employee WHERE mail='$email'");
```

Comment: This query is exactly like the second OP query. You just reversed the quotes (single with double). This doesn't solve his problem. I don't understand why he accepted it.

Answer (score 1):

Try below :

```
function getid($email){    
    $query=$this->db->query('SELECT e_id FROM employee WHERE mail='.$email.'"');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Write code with this format.

```
function getid($email){    
    $query=$this->db->query("SELECT e_id FROM employee WHERE mail='".$email."'");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just convert`'` to `"`

```
 $query=$this->db->query("SELECT e_id FROM employee WHERE mail='".$email."'");
```

Comment: @Masiorama as OP say their is no problem it with column name

Comment: @Masiorama you have given downvote to me but the write answer is my

Comment: Your answer is wrong, syntactically. Check again your usage of ".

Comment: Ah, you just fixed, this is way better now.

Answer (score 0):

Use these lines of code

```
function getid($email){ 
  if(!empty($email)){
      return $query=$this->db->query('SELECT e_id FROM employee WHERE mail="'.$email.'"');
  }
}
```